# Why does networkx show incorrect faces for traverse_face?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a planar graph. Edges and nodes for the figure below are: https://gist.github.com/nickponline/88848dc9cd10722fe8b7c4a2e628292f

I'm using `traverse_face` to display the face to the right of the red arrow in blue and to the left of the arrow in green. But the result I get is the image below. There are two things wrong, firstly the orientation seems to be flipped and secondly the outer faces does not include the white triangle (there is a white face at the top skipped). This does generate the correct result in some situation by not the graph below.

[image]

EDIT: My code is some like this:

```
H = nx.Graph( "nodes and edges in gist link" )
ret, P = nxa.planarity.check_planarity(H)

L = {}
R = {}

for edge in P.edges:


    rface = planar.traverse_face(edge[0], edge[1])
    lface = planar.traverse_face(edge[1], edge[0])

    R[edge] = rface
    L[edge] = lface

# Plotting edges edge and left and right face ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that when vertices have a geometric location the planar embedding might change the cycles.